# Returning changes variable (Java)

Tags: java, return

I have got the following code, it's function is as followed: You call the method and give a number with it. It will print out all the permutations for the number you gave it.

For example: you call the method like:

> permutations(3)

It will print out:

> 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321,

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    permutations(3);
}

public static void permutations(int n) {
    boolean used[] = new boolean[n];  //all set to false by default
    int perm[] = new int[n];
    permutations2(used, 0, perm);
}

private static void permutations2(boolean used[], int index, int perm[]) {
    if (index == used.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < perm.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(perm[i] + "");
        }
        System.out.print(", ");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
        if (!used[i]) {
            used[i] = true;
            perm[index] = i + 1;
            permutations2(used, index + 1, perm);
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

My question is at the return the statement. The variable 'index' changes when ever that return is called for some reason. Could anyone explain to me why this happens? The code works fine I just have trouble understanding how.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: This is a recursive algorithm, thus the new value of `index` is pushed on the stack as an argument, but for the caller the value remains the same. Tip: in your IDE set a breakpoint before the recursive call is made and see how the function is getting deeper and then returning.

Comment: It doesn't change. If you can specify exactly what it is that makes you think it does, we may be able to explain. Remember that you're calling the same function multiple times, stacked on itself, and each gets its own copy of the variables.

Comment: The value of 'index' doesn't change and will not change as long as you didn't assign it a new value!

Answer (score 0):

permutations2 is a recursive function, and you call it recursively on index + 1.

When the recursive base case is reached, ie index == used.length, return is called and the code goes one recursive call back to when index was one smaller.